# Comparing variances of variables derived from samples of different sizes

Tags: r, python, group-differences

I have a data frame, which I *group by* some variable v. Then I:

- subgroup the variable further by month
- for each month, I compute log loss and ROC AUC for points in a given group (level 1 grouping) and a given month (level 2 grouping). Scores (log loss and AUC) relate to another variable (y in classification).
- compute standard deviation of log losses and AUC's between months

So, what I would like to do is check how (un)stable scores are from month to month within a given group of v.

The problem is, different groups have different numbers of samples. For those with few samples scores variance tends to be bigger, and for those with many samples variance tends to be smaller.

How to offset these differences in sample size to compare variances meaningfully?

Comment: Assuming you compare variances *for the same variable* but within different groups, variances are all on the same scale, so should be directly comparable. The different sample sizes come in as different df if you do some hypothesis test of the variances.

Comment: You're either describing heteroskedasticity or standard errors, it's not clear which